# How to extends the model which do not have _attributes tables in Shopware 5?

Tags: plugins, attributes, custom-fields, shopware5

I want to extends the Premium Items module with some fields like(**max_order_value**, **visible_above_and_visible_below**) but it do not have its **_attributes**.

According to the documentation we should not modify Shopware 5 core tables.

Please guide what is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to write your own entity with a foreign key to the premium items table, and need to load the data on your own. Here you find some information about it https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/models/